Azure DevOps warning - Can't find loc string for key: Info_GotAndMaskAuth
In Azure DevOps, while running the build, I am getting the following warning in the stage of NPM AUDIT:

##[warning]Can't find loc string for key: Info_GotAndMaskAuth

Here is my current YAML configuration
npm audit
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'Audit'
    inputs:
      command: custom
      workingDir: 'Test-Project'
      verbose: false
      customCommand: audit

Please note that it is not impacting the build process
I tried updating the task to Npm@1.24.1 which stopped the build process with the following warning

A task is missing. The pipeline references a task called 'Npm'. This
usually indicates the task isn't installed, and you may be able to
install it from the Marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com.
(Task version 1.124.1, job 'Build', step ''.)

Any suggestion to solve this warning?

Which version of Azure DevOps are you using? Seems like there was a minor issue with the internal translation management: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/20120

Due to the issue on Npm@1 task, you can try to use a script task or Npm@0 task to run the command.

As @JSON Derulo mentioned, there is an known issue on the Npm@1 task.
As a workaround, you can try to use the script task or Npm@0 task to run the command.
- script: 'npm audit'
  displayName: 'Audit'
  workingDirectory: 'Test-Project'

Or
- task: Npm@0
  displayName: 'Audit'
  inputs:
    cwd: 'Test-Project'
    command: 'audit'

